# Como hacer CRUD en una tabla de bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, json, bootstrap-table

Estoy utilizando el bootstrap table, he visto un ejemplo donde esta tabla se puede editar. He tratado de poder editar con PHP y MySQL la tabla pero no obtengo resultado.

He mirado esta [documentación](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/editable) pero no obtengo resultados deseados, puedo ver la data pero no editarla.

mi codigo

```
<table data-pagination="true" data-search="true"
                              data-toggle="table"
                              data-url="controller/fetch.php"
                              data-pagination="true"
                              data-editable-url="controller/update.php">
             <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th id="code" data-sortable="true" data-field="Code" >Code</th>
                   <th id="name" data-editable="true" data-field="Name">Name </th>
                   <th id="mail" data-field="Mail" data-editable="true">Mail</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
</table>
```

javascritps

```
$('#name').editable({
                container: 'body',
                selector: 'td.Name',
                url: "controller/update.php",
                title: 'Employee Name',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                validate: function(value) {
                    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
                        return 'This field is required';
                    }
                }
            });
```

PHP

```
<?php
$query = "
 UPDATE personal SET ".$_POST["name"]." = '".$_POST["value"]."'
 WHERE Code = '".$_POST["pk"]."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien y si alguien tiene la forma de realizar la edición agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Que versión de bootstrap estás utilizando?

Comment: La verdad no te hiciste entender de la forma adecuada, lo que entiendo es que quieres editar una tabla de Bootstrap pero luego dices que lo haces con PHP y MYSQL lo cual no tiene fundamento con lo que realmente estas preguntando, por favor vuelve a redactar mejor tu pregunta y de esta manera podremos ayudarte.

Comment: @jecorrales Deseo editar la data de tabla ejemplo, si en `JSON `obtengo data nombre :"Juan" poder editarlo a "Juanito"

Comment: Entonces no quieres editar la tabla, quieres es editar los datos obtenidos, en pocas palabras quieres hacer un `CRUD` hacia tu base de datos. Para ello puedes intentar lo que te dicen en la ultima respuesta que te brindaron. Para la próxima debes de ser lo mas claro posible.

Comment: @jecorrales gracias trate de ser mas especifico, y si deseo hacer un crud en mi tabla aqui un ejemplo de lo  que quiero http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/

Comment: Vale, lo primero que debes de hacer es recorrer tu vector de datos para ser mostrados en la tabla, mostrando cada punto de lo que obtengas con tu `JSON`, ya sea el `id_persona`, `nombre_persona`, `apellido_persona`, `edad_persona`... ya cuando tengas dichos datos (esto a manera de ejemplo) como tienes el `id`al cual hacer referencia en tu base de datos entonces lo mandas con algún evento onclick de `javascript` en un botón, algo como `onclick="editarPersona(id_persona, nombre_persona,...etc)"` y ya se lo pasas por el método POST a tu backend que en este caso sería `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo. Para comenzar a utilizar bootstrap en su versión 4.x Seria necesario que comiences a leer la documentación de dicha librería

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-dark" data-pagination="true" data-search="true"
                              data-toggle="table"
                              data-url="controller/fetch.php"
                              data-pagination="true"
                              data-editable-url="controller/update.php">
             <thead>
                  <tr>
                   <th id="code" data-sortable="true" data-field="Code" >Code</th>
                   <th id="name" data-editable="true" data-field="Name">Name </th>
                   <th id="mail" data-field="Mail" data-editable="true">Mail</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Pedro</td>
             <td>p@pedro.es</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Puedo utilizar el table pero este lo quiero poder editar, aqui el ejemplo http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/

Answer (score 1):

Puedes revisar este [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Editable-Tables-jQuery-Bootstrap-Bootstable.html) lo use y me funciono aquí tienes los resultados:

```js
//This will make all the table cells editable.
$('table').SetEditable();

//If you want to specify the table columns to be editable.
/*$('table').SetEditable({
  columnsEd: "0,1"
});*/

//Event handlers available.
/*$('table').SetEditable({
  onEdit: function() {},
  onDelete: function() {},
  onBeforeDelete: function() {},
  onAdd: function() {}
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Editable-Tables-jQuery-Bootstrap-Bootstable/bootstable.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table" id="table"
  data-url="data/url.json"
  data-id-field="id"
  data-editable-emptytext="Default empty text."
  data-editable-url="/my/editable/update/path">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-1" data-field="id" data-sortable="true" data-align="center">#</th>
      <th class="col-md-4" data-field="name" data-editable="true">Name</th>
      <th class="col-md-7" data-field="description" data-editable="true" data-editable-emptytext="Custom empty text.">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>p@pedro.es</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```